# Where is the project startup order saved?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

And can I edit it by hand? I have over a hundred projects and I can't keep reordering them by clicking a hundred times around until they are all in the correct order in this dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [SwitchStartupProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571) extension. With this extension you can reorder only startup projects, that should be easier then reordering all projects in VS dialog.